# Cant compile latest firebase core library

Tags: android, firebase

I was using`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'` and tried to update my dependencies to `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'` but no luck.

All I get is:

> Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'

I use google play services 3.1.0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I have solve this issue by following these steps:

**Configure Gradle's**

*build.Gradle(Project:{ProjectName})*

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
```

*gradle-wrapper.properties*

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

**Configure for Dependencies Error**

1. Open `SDK Manager`
2. Select `SDK Tools` Tab
3. Expand `Support Repository`
4. Select `Google Repository`
5. Update It, make sure you have version `54` and above, after update.

Comment: I wonder how did you find this solution? I mean How would I find a solution without external help?

Comment: just read the google doc content more carefully, when you trying to do any new implementation in android..... :)

Answer (score 8):

Just update the Google Repository.

1. Go to SDK Manager
2. Select Android SDK under Appearance and Behaviour
3. Select SDK Tools
4. Extract Support Repository and Update the Google Repository to 54.