# Google Play Service version conflict for Firebase 11.0.2 libraries

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-play-services

I updated the Firebase libraries to the latest version but I am unable to Sync the gradle and it results in the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:processProductionDebugGoogleServices'.
>
> > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is
> >     available at
> >     https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
> >     or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.0.2.

As it states, I updated the gms version to 11.0.2 as well. Here's my gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

//other gradle config

String googleSupportVersion = '25.3.1'
String googlePlayServicesVersion = '11.0.2'

compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$googleSupportVersion"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$googleSupportVersion"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
compile "com.android.support:design:$googleSupportVersion"
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: hope this will help you....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44585799/cant-compile-latest-firebase-core-library/44589930#44589930

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. Thank you though @AniruddhParihar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your google service plugin to 3.1.0

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `def googlePlayServicesVersion = '11.0.2'` instead of `String googlePlayServicesVersion = '11.0.2'`